# can't access R-Pi after setting static Ip

Tags: raspbian

I used to control my raspberry using VNC or ssh software where it's connected to the same network that my laptop connects to.
I was having a small problem, that I need to know the Ip of raspberry each time it connects to the local network, then I decided to set a static IP by adding some line to /etc/network/interfaces

> when I reboot the system, it became unable to connect toy local network, and I'm sure that all configuration of static IP are true.
>
> > How can I edit inteface file from my laptop if I connect just the SD card?
> >     Because SD card looks diffrent when I opened it from laptop  (windows 8), And I haven't found /etc/ ....

I'm grateful for any help.

Comment: you need linux to edit the root filesystem which is in the second partition of the sdcard (windows only ever shows the first partition of usb/sd/etc devices) - virtualbox could help

Comment: Thank you so much ... please I want to know ... what is the problem of not connecting in your opinion?

Comment: My opinion is that you messed up /etc/network/interfaces - anything in the output of dmesg obvious?

Comment: Sorry. ... I didn't understand .... my network/interfaces file contain the ip address and netmask and default gateway. .. it makes me confused to locate the error ?

Comment: Make a ubuntu live usb. Allways nice to have

Comment: how about you include the contents of /etc/network/interfaces file in the question, then we'll be able to see if you messed it up or not

Comment: Sorry @EL3PHANTEN .. What do u mean of (live usb?

Comment: It's no use asking for log files when the OP can't access his R-Pi at all.

Comment: It's pretty easy to plug in a keyboard and a monitor

Comment: @AbdulkaderKhateeb http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu Then you can boot on the usb, and you are running ubuntu from the usb. You can do that with most linux distros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take out the card and put it into another computer, then edit the `interfaces` file and restore it to what it was before your unfortunate modification.

On any Linux system, that would be easy, as the card just shows up. On a Windows computer that will not work, as the file system you need to edit is an `ext4` system, which Windows cannot read. All you can see is the *other* file system on the card, which is a DOS file system. However, if you install a ext4 driver like [ext2fsd](http://www.ext2fsd.com/) on your Windows system, the ext4 file system can be read and written.

Comment: See also [here](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/37920/5538) for the correct way to set up a static IP on Raspbian.

Answer (score 1):

> adding some line to /etc/network/interfaces

Looks like you weren't familiar with the config file. Do you maybe remember what did you put into this file?

As for editing the config file, you don't have to do this from another computer, you can use HDMI output and a USB keyboard to log in and re-edit the file.